# animate the cell of a datagrid in WPF when some condition is True?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I am currently working on datagrid-WPF, which is displaying a table from a database.
The table displays the information about the Student Results as PASS AND FAIL. 
Now I would like to animate the cells on the datagrid-cell as 
GREEN color when its is PASS and RED color when it is Fail.

How to achieve this in c# and XAML ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something as `DataGridTemplateColumn` ..

follows an example..

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignCell}" Header="Result" IsReadOnly="True" Width="*" Visibility="Visible" CanUserResize="True" SortMemberPath="GAIN_AT_POSITION" CanUserSort="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Background="{Binding GainHighlight}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding GAIN_AT_POSITION, StringFormat=N2}" Foreground="{Binding GainForeGround}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

ps: `GainHighlight` is a propety in my Class to binding on the UI.

I hope have helped.

Best.

Answer (score 1):

Use a style and a converter

```
 public class SomeConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string cellValue = value.ToString();
        return cellValue == "PASS";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding List}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <myApp:SomeConverter
        x:Key="SomeConverter">
    </myApp:SomeConverter>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="FlashStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger 
                Binding="{Binding Col1, 
                Converter={StaticResource SomeConverter}}" 
                Value="True" >
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard 
                            x:Name="Blink" 
                            AutoReverse="True" 
                            RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <EasingColorKeyFrame 
                                    KeyTime="00:00:01" 
                                    Value="Green" />
                            </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn 
        Binding="{Binding Col1}" 
        CellStyle="{StaticResource FlashStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn 
        Binding="{Binding Col2}"></DataGridTextColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

And include a second data trigger for value = false in the xaml and trigger the color red

And add the style onto the datagrid column

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Binding="{Binding SomeCol}" 
    CellStyle="{StaticResource FlashStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
<DataGridTextColumn 
    Binding="{Binding AnotherCol}"
    CellStyle="{StaticResource FlashStyle}"></DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks indeed. I have a problem including CultureInfo culture, my      Intellisense accepts only CultureInfoIetfLanguageTagConverter culture.
and this creates a problem. I have already included System.Globalization.CultureInfo. But still I face this issue.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - please could you be a bit more specific about the problem?

Comment: If it is an intellisense problem then do the following Delete the files in this folder: %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\ReflectedSchemas vs2010

%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ReflectedSchemas vs2012

Comment: I have a problem here
       <myApp:SomeConverter
           x:Key="SomeConverter">
       </myApp:SomeConverter>
It says The type myApp not found, missing reference or namespace.

Comment: Ok what is the namespace of the class you've written for the converter? You need to <myNameSpace:YourConverterClassName x:Key="WhateverYouWantToCallTheKey"> </myNameSpace:YourConverterClassName> just replace myNameSpace, YourConverterClassName and WhateverYouWantToCallTheKey with whatever they are in your local app.. And I reckon I deserve a few more votes on this one ;-)